# Android NDK get md5 of the binary file

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, md5

### DESCRIPTION

I'm trying to get md5 hash of the binary (`.dex`) file, which is stored in the `/data/data/my.package.name/file.dex`. I use Android NDK (C++).

### PROBLEM

Several ways to get hash of the file:

1. From my laptop: `md5sum file.dex` -> `5a65273b2ee336ad2c45a9306be162f6`
2. Using `adb shell`:`md5sum file.dex` -> `5a65273b2ee336ad2c45a9306be162f6`
3. From my C++ code:

```cpp
    int err = 0;
    zip *z = zip_open(getBaseApkAbsolutePath(), 0, &err);

    const char *name = "classes.dex";
    struct zip_stat st;
    zip_stat_init(&st);
    zip_stat(z, name, 0, &st);

    char *contents = new char[st.size];

    zip_file *f = zip_fopen(z, name, 0);
    zip_fread(f, contents, st.size);

    std::ofstream ofstream;
    ofstream.open("/data/data/my.package/classes.dex", std::ofstream::binary);
    ofstream.write(contents, st.size);

    joyee::MD5 md5 = joyee::MD5();
    md5.update(contents, sizeof(contents));
    md5.finalize();

    LOG(md5.toString());
    LOG(joyee::md5(contents));

    zip_fclose(f);
    zip_close(z);
```

And then I get this -> `aaaeb407992f9fe57cc6235ece90ec35`

### CLARIFICATION

1. My code works well with simple string like `Hello, World!`
2. MD5 implementation works well

### QUESTION

How can I get md5 hash of the binary file in Android using C++ ?

Comment: What is that extra byte in `contents` for? Apparently your `MD5` function takes a length parameter, so no NUL terminator should be necessary.

Comment: @Michael I just forgot to remove it. It doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
md5.update(contents, sizeof(contents));
```

You're taking the size of your *pointer* (which is 4 or 8) instead of the buffer it points to. So effectively you are calculating the md5sum of those first few bytes. Pass `st.size` instead to check the full file.